# Java 7: How to execute parallel tasks in batches?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have three web-service calls that can run in parallel. Hence, I'm using a fixed pool of 3 threads to run them.

Now I want to process a couple more web-service calls, that can run in parallel, but only after the first three calls are processed.

How can I batch them? I want the ones inside a batch to run in parallel. And every batch only runs after the previous batch is completed.

So far I am only working with three services. How can I batch them and start using another 2 services?

```
  ExecutorService peopleDataTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

  Future<Collection<PeopleInterface>> task1 = null;
  if (condition) { 
      task1 = peopleDataTaskExecutor.submit(buildTask1Callable(mycontext));
  }

  Future<Map<String, Task2Response>> task2 = peopleDataTaskExecutor.submit(buildTask2Callable(mycontext));

  Future<Map<String, Task3Response>> task3 = null;
  task3 = peopleDataTaskExecutor.submit(buildTask3Callable(mycontext));

  peopleDataTaskExecutor.shutdown();
  try {
      peopleDataTaskExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }

  Collection<PeopleInterface> task1Data = null;
  try {
      task1Data = task1 != null ? task1.get() : null;
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  }

  Map<String, Task2Response> task2Data = null;
  try {
      task2Data = task2.get();
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  }

  Map<String, Task3Response> task3Data = null;
  if (task3 != null) {
      try {
          task3Data = task3.get();
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to execute batches sequentially is to use the `invokeAll()` method. It accepts a collection of tasks, submits them to the executor and waits until completion (or until a timeout expires). Here's a simple example that executes three batches sequentially. Each batch contains three tasks running in parallel:

```
public class Program {
    static class Task implements Callable<Integer> {
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private final int no;
        Task(int no) {
            this.no = no;
        }
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(5000));
            System.out.println("Task " + no + " finished");
            return no;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        processBatch(executor, 1);
        processBatch(executor, 2);
        processBatch(executor, 3);
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static void processBatch(ExecutorService executor, int batchNo) throws InterruptedException {
        Collection batch = new ArrayList<>();
        batch.add(new Task(batchNo * 10 + 1));
        batch.add(new Task(batchNo * 10 + 2));
        batch.add(new Task(batchNo * 10 + 3));
        List<Future> futures = executor.invokeAll(batch);
        System.out.println("Batch " + batchNo + " proceseed");
    }
}
```

You can use those `Future`s in the `processBatch()` method to check the completion states of the tasks (were they executes successfully or terminated because of an exception), obtain their return values etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get the Future when adding a batch ? Otherwise the logic to get the Future from List<Future> through index looks cluttered.

Comment: If you add a batch, you get a collection of futures. One future can be only obtained through calling 'submit()'. But in the latter case it's your responsibility to wait on each future until it completes or a timeout expires. So, if you have a collection of tasks, you have to iterate through their futures either way. `invokeAll()` is simpler because it doesn't force you to iterate on submitting. With `submit()` you have to iterate twice - to submit tasks and to process results.